# Confusing CSS, can anyone explain please

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure why the last image 6.png is selected, when all the images are direct descendants of the div shape. Thanks for your help its much appreciated.
From what I understand it should select all the divs because they are all direct descendants of the div `#shape`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>3D image</title>
    <style>
    body,html{
        width:100%; 
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    body{
        background:-webkit-gradient(radial,800 
               64,950, 500, 400, 40, from(#1F1F1F),  to(#FFFFFF));
    }

    #container{
        width:100%;
    }

    #shape{
        position:relative;
        top:160px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }

    #shape > div{
        position:absolute;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="shape">
        <div class="one"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/persian"><img src="images/2.png"></a></div>
        <div class="two"><a href="http://www.aljazeera.com"><img src="images/3.png"></a></div>
        <div class="three"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news"><img src="images/4.png"></a></div>
        <div class="four"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="images/1.png"></a></div>
        <div class="five"><a href="http://www.html5nurse.com"><img  src="images/5.png"></a></div>
        <div class="six"><a href="http://www.cnn.com"><img src="images/6.png"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Argh! Please use more sensible indentation, this is not easy to read.

Comment: Do you mean that <div class="six"> is the only div selected?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking though. Try describing what you what to happen, what does happen and what the difference between the two is.

Comment: yes why is class six selected

Comment: If you're confused why only the last div is visible on the screen, it's because you have `position:absolute` for all the divs so they'll be on top of each other. If the images are of same size they'll cover each other.

Comment: try `float:left` instead.

Comment: also, if you're looking for a reason why this is 'confusing CSS', its because you didn't indent it properly!

Comment: Isn't it kind of ironic that the username of the OP is `stacked ontop`?

Comment: @Joum wow, yeah it is actually lol

Answer (score 3):

All of them are selected.

They are overlapping eachother, as in they all have the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#shape > div{
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
```

for

```
#shape > div{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
```

And you should see the difference.